# Shell variables within match() with a date regex

Tags: shell, awk

In a shell script, I have a couple of variables:

```
last_month=$(date +%m -d "-1 month")
year=$(date +%Y -d "-1 month")
```

That the third field (a date) in a file (using "|" as separator) must match:

```
awk -v awk_last_month="$last_month" -v awk_year="$year" -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} match($3,/^[0-9]+\/awk_last_month\/awk_year/)' "$export_name"
```

I am sure the field has (many!) matching rows and I have made some tests to make AWK print the passed-in variables (awk_last_month and awk_year):  it does print 'em, but when they are used within match() the matching fails and I end up with an empty file. I thought it has something to do with the date slashes (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk), but as per code above they are escaped.

Comment: Can you provide sample input with expected outout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff between slashes is a literal regex without access to variables; but the second argument to `match()` can be a string, which you can interpolate variables into by regular Awk mechanisms - viz.

```
match($3, "^[0-9]+\/" awk_last_month "\/" awk_year)
```

or

```
match($3, sprintf("^[0-9]+\\/%s\\/%s", awk_last_month, awk_year))
```

or a myriad other string manipulation operations available in the language itself.

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice command, very nice use of `sprintf` didn't know it could be used inside match, thanks a TON for sharing sir. Can we use this `sprintf` in all kind of `awk`s? Or it is specific to any `awk`, could you please clarify once please.

Comment: It's in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) but many of the lesser Awks do not implement the full POSIX spec. However, it's technically very easy if you have `printf` so I see no reason any implementation would leave it out.